# Python Gameobjects Install

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using Pycharm 2019.2 with Python 3.7 (Windows 10).  I am trying to install Gameobjects with this.  Unfortunately, the code available on the Internet is from 2007 and will not set up on my computer.  How does one install gameobjects so that it will function properly with Pycharm?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use a library that had no activity for 13 years?

Comment: Is there a newer library that has the same funcitonality?

Comment: What is the ```gameobjects``` functionality?

Comment: matrix multiplication

Comment: If you just want matrix multiplication, you can use ```numpy``` https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html